# WPF DataBinding (CommandParameter not working)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, command, commandparameter

I can't get my binding to work. My ActiveView has a ListView (x:Name="MyListView") as well as a view model as it's data context.

I have the following RibbonButton (RibbonControlLibrary):

```
<r:RibbonButton Label="Update Software" 
    LargeImageSource="/Ganymed.App.UI;component/Images/plain-update.png"
    Command="{Binding ActiveView.DataContext.UpdateSoftwareCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ActiveView.MyListView.SelectedItems}"/>
```

The command binding itself works fine. But I can't get the CommandParameter to work. I want to sent along the selected items of the ActiveView's ListView in order to decide whether or not to enabled the command. Am I missing something when binding the CommandParameter?

To clarify the structue:

MainWindow.xaml (contains the RibbonButton, DataContext = MainWindowViewModel)

MainWindowViewModel.cs contains the property ActiveView

ActiveView (contains the MyListView, DataContext = ActiveViewViewModel)

ActiveViewViewModel.cs contains the UpdateSoftwareCommand

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it bee ActiveView.MyListView instead of ActiveView.ListView, cause you say the name is "MyListView" ?

Comment: Hi that was my fault when copying the code. I have changed the name in the example to not confuse anybody else.

Comment: How does your code for UpdateSoftwareCommand look like? If you use DelegateCommand then you should use DelegateCommand<TypeOfCommandParameter> version

Comment: In our software solution we have an ActionCommand : ICommand implementation which we use as commands.

Comment: What is ActiveView, is it a UserControl?

Comment: Yes ActiveView is a UserControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility :

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type r:RibbonButton}}, Path=SelectedItems}"
```

Another, you could just add a property SelectedItems to your ViewModel, bind it and have it always in sync and ready for command to operate on

Comment: Your solution is not working. I guess it is not working since the ListView is not an Ancestor of the Button within the Visual Tree.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put as the ancenstor whatever control that has the Binding to your ViewModel